# How to continue the countdown timer after closing ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, timer, uidatepicker

I use `UIDatePicker` to implement a countdown timer.After loading view`datePickerMode` set CountDownTimer:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
self.countDownTimer.datePickerMode=UIDatePickerModeCountDownTimer;
}
```

First,set the countdown time in `UIDatePicker`,then press the button to start the countdown:

```
- (IBAction)StartCountdown:(id)sender {
    [sender setTitle:@"Cancel" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    countDownInterval = (NSTimeInterval)countDownTimer.countDownDuration;
    remainder = countDownInterval;
    afterRemainder = countDownInterval - remainder % 60 ;
    //call updateCountDown()
    timer=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(updateCountDown) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
```

call `updateCountDown()`:

```
-(void)updateCountDown{
    afterRemainder --;
    int hours = (int)(afterRemainder/(60*60));
    int mins = (int)(((int)afterRemainder/60)-(hours * 60));
    int secs = (int)(((int)afterRemainder - (60 * mins) - (60 * hours *60)));
    NSString *displayText = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%02u : %02u : %02u",hours,mins,secs];
    self.displayLabel.text = displayText;
}
```

Action can execute properly, but when I jump out of this view and will not perform timer is zero, how do I operate the timer can be sustained after the jump view?

Comment: means you need to run that after going another view also ?

Comment: i think you declare method in app delegate then you start the timer and access another view.

Comment: I have a `viewcontroller` named `timeViewContorller`, I'm in the view settings `UIDatePicker` and set  `button` to start and cancel it.

Comment: Even if I switch to another `viewController` or turn off the APP, the countdown timer continues in execution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do:

1. When you jump out the view, let save state at this time to NSUserDefaults

   - The remain time, maybe in seconds
   - The current system time at that time, exam: 13:20:15
2. When you open the view again:

   - Get current system time, sub it with saved system time (A)
   - Sub saved remain time (in seconds) with (A) and continue to countdown.

Just a idea, but hope it helps

Comment: If you do so, then jump view timer will stop, right?

Comment: Yes, the timer only works when we go to jumper view again

Comment: I hope that even out of view still works with my timer

Comment: I didn't get how to you want to do that. But I think with your idea, you should make Singleton for the Timer (a static timer object) and static "timer selector" too. Event jump view is killed (out), the timer still works, still calls "timer selector"

Answer (score 1):

1. The best and clean way to create a singleton class and declare your timer inside as a property inside it . so there is only one instance of the timer object throughout the application .
2. Another way is to declare timer in the app delegate class which also holds the object throughout the application

Comment: I'm sorry I was a beginner, you can provide some examples for me to learn it?