# How to call ViewController's UILabel in Singleton

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nstimer

**I asked a question**：[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31200859/how-to-continue-the-countdown-timer-after-closing-viewcontroller/31201325?noredirect=1#comment50463049_31201325)

After discussing this issue, I will rewrite the original program, become `Singleton` methods.

I'll call timer which way to write in `MySingleton`,then `TimerViewController` inside to call `MySingleton`'s method :

**`MySingleton.h`**

```
@interface MySingleton : NSObject
{   
   int remainder;
   NSTimer *timer;
   NSTimeInterval countDownInterval;
   int hours;
   int mins;
   int secs;
}
@property(nonatomic, retain)NSString *displayText;
@property int afterRemainder;
+(MySingleton*) getInstance;
-(void)doSomethingWithString:(int*)parameter;
@end
```

**`MySingleton.m`**

```
-(void)doSomethingWithString:(int*)parameter {
    remainder = *parameter;
    _afterRemainder = *parameter - remainder % 60 ;
    timer=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(updateCountDown)userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
 }
-(void)updateCountDown{
    _afterRemainder --;
    hours = (int)(_afterRemainder/(60*60));
    mins = (int)(((int)_afterRemainder/60)-(hours * 60));
    secs = (int)(((int)_afterRemainder - (60 * mins) - (60 * hours *60)));
    displayText = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%02u : %02u : %02u",hours,mins,secs];
}
```

**`TimerViewController.h`**

```
@interface TimerViewController : UIViewController
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIDatePicker *CountDown;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *LabTimer;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *BtnStart;

- (IBAction)StartCmd:(id)sender;
@end
```

**`TimerViewController.m`**

Here to call timer,`UILabel` is placed `TimerViewController.m`

```
- (IBAction)StartCmd:(id)sender {
    MySingleton* singleton = [MySingleton getInstance];
    nowInterval=(NSTimeInterval)CountDown.countDownDuration;
    nowTimer = nowInterval;
    [singleton doSomethingWithString:&(nowTimer)];
}
```

`TimerViewContorller` have one `Label` call `LabTimer`, `MySingleton` have a `NSString` call `display text` I want to call `LabTimer` in `MySingleton`,and displays `displaytext` in `LabTimer`
I don't know how to do it?

Comment: can u show  error? 


PS:
`-(void)doSomethingWithString:(int*)parameter` - delete "*" , `int` and `NSInteger` is primitive types.

Comment: @CHUB, what DO you see? What's inside `displayText`?

Comment: @Gal In `displayText`  I see nil

Comment: @KonstantinKryzhanovsky I think delete * is wrong,because displaytext in NSlog show 4294418679: 4294418691: 4294418694

Answer (score 0):

don't understand u're question. But show u how singleton may work.

so:

u have some Singleton class: `MySingleton`.

`h.file`

```
@interface MySingleton : NSObject {
}
+ (id)sharedManager;
- (void)SomeMethod:(int)someParameter;
@end
```

`m file`

```
@implementation MySingleton

+ (id)sharedManager {
      static MySingleton *sharedMyManager = nil;
      static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
      dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
          sharedMyManager = [[self alloc] init];
      });
   return sharedMyManager;
 }


#pragma mark - Some public Method
- (void)SomeMethod:(int)someParameter
{
     // code here
     [self somePrivateMethod];
}

#pragma mark - Some private Method
- (void)somePrivateMethod {
   // code here
}
```

And u can use this class inside u're `MainClassController`:

like this:

```
// some code before
/* call singleton `Some Method` */
[[MySingleton sharedManager] SomeMethod:'int value'];
// code after
```

Maybe its helps u . Good luck)

Comment: I have written a singleton, but I don‘t know how to show the countdown time in Label

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the text of the UILabel when the timer fires. Move the assignment statement that assigns displayText into the timer's action method (`updateCountDown`).

By the way, I don't understand UILabel.text = ... I assume that this is a syntax error in your code.

When you do an assignment like this:

> myLabel.text = displayText;

what happens is that the right-hand side expression (a single variable in this case) is evaluated and its value at the time the statement is executed is assigned to the text property of the UILabel (and the user sees it). If you change the value of displayText later, that will make no difference to what the user sees - the assignment to the text property has to be executed again. I hope this is clear.

To solve your problem:

1. Add a weak reference to TimeViewController to MySingleton:

@property (weak) TimeViewController* myViewController;

2. Before calling doSomethingWithString, assign self to singleton

> MySingleton* singleton = [MySingleton getInstance];
>   nowInterval=(NSTimeInterval)CountDown.countDownDuration; nowTimer =
>   nowInterval; singleton.myViewController = self; [singleton
>   doSomethingWithString:&(nowTimer)];

3. Whenever the timer fires, call a method of TimeViewController

> ... displayText = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%02u : %02u :
>   %02u",hours,mins,secs]; [self.myViewController
>   updateDisplay:displayText];

Comment: thank you @Michael L
let me put it this way, `TimerViewContorller` have one `Label` call `LabTimer`,
`MySingleton` have a `NSString` call `displaytext`
I want to call `LabTimer` in `MySingleton`,and displays `display text` in `LabTimer`

Comment: Since you have a singleton, get it in the updateCountDown method, and call a new method of MySingleton that sets the text value of the label to displayText

Comment: so how can I do to call `LabTimer` in `MySingleton`?

Comment: Thank you for helping me a lot but I still do not understand what is meant by point 3,meant to create a method in TimeViewController to call it?

Comment: implement "updateDisplayText" in TimeViewController. The body of the method should assign its argument to the text of the UILabel. Have you considered doing an online Objective-C course?

Comment: So - did you get this to work? Do you understand it now?

Comment: YES! I creat `-(void)updateDisplay:(NSString*)parameter` and I can see the countdown time

Comment: But after I quit `TimerViewController`,`Label` can't show